# How can I calculate the formula of $ \dim( N([T]_B))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

given vector space $V$ so that $\dim(V)$ is finite , base $B$ to $V$, and linear-transformation $T:V \to V$.

How can I calculate the formula of $ \dim( N([T]_B))$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that for [Rank–nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), the dimension of the Null space is

$$\dim( N([T]_B))=\dim V-\text{rank} [T]_B$$

Comment: How you got it?

Comment: @MasterQuestion It is a trivial result from rank-nullity theorem